# I have a button inside a ControlTemplate. How do I get a reference to it?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I just want to enable or disable the button inside a ControlTemplate for a WPF Editor that I'm using.

Comment: It would be nice to know more specific information -- including seeing your XAML and knowing your intentions -- so that we can make our answers that much more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Joel that the preferred method would be to trigger the setting of the button's Enabled property with xaml markup, either through a trigger or by binding the Enabled value to another dependency property, possibly on a parent element, likely with the help of a ValueConverter.

However, if you have to do it explicitly in C#, you can use the FindName() method on the template property of the button.  There's an MSDN 'how to' [linked here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

My I recommend that buttons are easily controled through RoutedUICommands - including easily enabling and disabling them. Commands do not need any type of reference to the Button so this solves your problem, too.

See here:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding 
        Command="{x:Static local:MyCommands.MyCommand}"
        Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"
        CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="Label">
        <Button Command="{x:Static local:MyCommands.MyCommand}">
            <TextBlock>
                Click Me
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Label Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">1</Label>
    <Label Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">2</Label>
    <Label Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">3</Label>
    <Label Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">4</Label>
    <Label Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">5</Label>
</StackPanel>
```

Use this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // your logic here
        int _Integer = -1;
        int.TryParse(e.Parameter.ToString(), out _Integer);
        e.CanExecute = _Integer % 2 == 0;
    }

    private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something when clicked
    }
}

public static class MyCommands
{
    public static RoutedUICommand MyCommand = new RoutedUICommand();
}
```

Looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't be doing that explicitly, but instead be setting it with Triggers in the `ControlTemplate` itself. These Triggers would be reacting to some other change, and would set the `Enabled` property of the `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with buttons in controlTemplates & dataTemplates. I find triggers are often too cumbersome to provide exactly what my clients want, I ended up with too many converters. The method I first tried was to define these more difficult templates inline so they could be bound to commands (& codebehind events) on my screens ViewModel.

if you are templating your own control, I should mention the easiest method is to simply name the button then use something like this:

```
hourHand   = this.Template.FindName( "PART_HourHand",   this ) as Rectangle;
```

Recently however, I've changed tact (back to indevidual files.. RE-USE!) but started adding a ViewModel (of sorts) which I suffix `...TemplateCommandStore` to all my templates that get a bit complex. I even use this when templating my customcontrols (for consistency, mostly)

```
public class BookingDetailsTemplateCommandStore
{
    public OpenWindowCommand_Command OpenWindowCommand_Command { get; set; }

    public BookingDetailsTemplateCommandStore()
    {
        OpenWindowCommand_Command = new OpenWindowCommand_Command( this );
    }       
}
```

I can then happily use this command in a template. You can also pass control references into the command store by binding a (dependancy?) property to it to capture events & excise more precise control over your templates.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type LeisureServices:BookingSummary}">
    <Border Height="50" otherStyling="xyz">
        <Border.Resources>
            <local:BookingDetailsTemplateCommandStore x:Key="CommandStore" />
        </Border.Resources>
        <DockPanel>
            <Button otherStyling="xyz"
                    Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource CommandStore},
                                      Path=OpenWindowCommand_Command}" />
```

*MVVM:* I find that so long as graphical logic is just that, and completely distinct from business logic, this methodology doesn't interfere with MVVM. In essence I add consistent C# code-ability to Templates, which anyone who spent too much time in winforms might miss as much as I do.